# Unable to enable "User may sync settings and app data"

Tags: azure, active-directory

Disclaimer: Some messages/menus are translated from Dutch and might not match literally.

So, in my search for enabling Account settings sync in Windows, i ended up in Azure, but there I stranded.

My goal is to enable Account settings sync in Windows (found under *Start->Settings->Accounts->Sync your settings*) This is now grayed out with a red message at the top "Synchronization is not available for your account. Please contact your system administrator to resolve this."

Apparently this has something to do with my Office 365 account being listed under the *Start->Settings->Accounts->Access to work or school* as "Connected to Azure AD from [company name]"
When i try to disconnect my PC from this organisation network it says "This PC is not added to a domain"

So searching on it lead me to the Azure AD portal when i should enable the "User may sync settings and app data" found under Azure *Active Directory->Devices->Device Settings*. However, this setting is missing from my portal. Comparing with screenshots found on the internet it seems to be the only setting on that page that is missing.

That lead me to enable Enterprise State Roaming found under *Azure Active Directory->Devices->Enterprise State Roaming*, but this is missing completely from the navigation menu.

Am i missing something in any of the steps?

I've read some people are trialing an Azure subscription, but i'm not. I only have an Office 365 Business 
subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Look like your system is not in the Domain. You can put the your system in Domain as below --
Go to PC>>Properties>>Change Setting>>Change(under Computer Name)>>Put the Domain Name(under Member Of)>>OK

After that you should add system to Azure AD as below path -
Start->Settings->Accounts->Access to work or school as "Connected to Azure AD from [company name] .
and should able to login through Azure AD authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you're connected to the domain it's at the behest of the domain settings whether or not you can synch and there's not much a user can do about that, and if you disconnect from the domain just to get away from the domain settings to enable it you're not going to have access to the domain.

If you want to synch AND be a part of the domain you have to contact the domain admin.

Comment: I am the domain admin. I'm the sole user and administrator of the office 365 account. How can i enable it then?

Comment: would need more info then

there's a difference between an office 365 account admin and a domain admin

are you on a domain for your work or anything? if your actual domain admin doesn't want you accessing the sync options for MS365 then there's not much you can do. also are you going into the admin console of the MS 365 account? if you're the only user you're not admin by default which can be confusing and you don't necessarily see the admin console when you log in either

there's videos on getting to the ms365 admin console in a browsers it changes all the time so it can be a pain

Comment: I own the domain as well and have setup the DNS records. I also created the office 365 account myself and have full access to https://admin.microsoft.com/ Where can i then configure to allow sync for my domain?